# Email spam mentioning stackoverflow profile

Tags: discussion, spam

I received an interesting email this morning that appears to me to be spam:

> Hello , I  came across your profie in
>   (stackoverflow.com) and I will like us
>   to have a  goodrelationship and to
>   know much better .my name is 
>   Blessing,  i am single and never
>   marriage.I will wait for your reply .
>   you can contact me at this my email
>   address ( [--------------]@yahoo.com) so
>   that i can send you my picture andmore
>   about myself.  waiting to hear from
>   you .
>
> PLEASE CONTACT ME DIRECTLY WITH THIS
>   EMAIL ([--------------]@yahoo.com)

It has many of the hallmarks of spam, but my email isn't listed in my SO profile, so one of the following must be true:

- They made their bot harvest emails from sites linked from SO
- They collected addresses by hand
- They got the emails from the database (I imagine this is stripped, but don't know)
- They got it from the openid provider (does openid give out info without credentials?)
- They sent the same message to their entire mailing list, hoping to catch out a few people with the name of a specific website (and thus bringing new SO users to SO in the process who are wondering what their profile is doing there)
- It isn't spam (Sorry blessing - I'm not interested in getting to know people that write email that looks exactly like spam)

I'm interested in other possibilities, and to hear if anyone else received something similar.

-Adam

Comment: Spaces before punctuation?! Blessing's not a keeper, even if she has never marriage.

Comment: re send her picture once you get it

Comment: Spam is a multi-billion dollar business, and they still can't afford to hire QA?

Comment: If this isn't the spam that comes with the photo already attached, you're playing with a soft sell.

Comment: @Jonathan: They make billions of dollars without QA. Why should they bother? Never touch a flooding cash flow ;)

Comment: @Eric : What are you talking about ?

Comment: @Jonathan: Are you implying that without typos, you'd respond more amorously to Blessing?

Comment: @devinb: There's nothing like a well constructed sentence. As a programmer, you should be able to appreciate that this spam doesn't even compile.

Comment: @John Smithers, Touche!

Comment: @Welbog: Eric talks about this: http://www.keeper.com/aboutkeeper.html Don't you, Eric :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely spam: http://www.aarp.org/community/MPHS10

> Hello ,I came across your profile in and I will like us to have a good relationship and to know much better .my name is grace, i am single and never marriage.I will wait for your reply . you can contact me at this my email address (grracemabar@yahoo.com) so that i can send you my picture and more about myself. waiting to hear from you

As you pointed out, your website address is mentioned in a few places. From a cursory glance at your site, I didn't see any public email address, but a whois search brought up one. I won't post it here, but it's the primary address for your domain. Who knows, maybe they collected your domain from here, looked it up on a whois search, and collected the administrative contact details..

Comment: Nice find.  Same thing, though the emails are different.  The latter part of the email (mabar) is very similar to my version.

Comment: They seem to have placeholders - I saw some other results on Google mentioning other sites in place of "stackoverflow.com."

Comment: So then did they spam millions of people about their "stackoverflow" accounts, or do they have some way of knowing that a certain address has a stackoverflow account? SO is a very particular site - not like a bank or large organization.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering, Jon B.

Comment: @Jon B, was it your primary email for your domain that was spammed? If so, this is available to the public via a simple whois.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't actually link to *your* stack overflow profile though, does it? It sounds like the equivalent of a 'your account with bank X has been suspended' spam. There are probably millions of people around the world looking at this message and wondering what on earth '(stackoverflow.com)' is as we speak...

Comment: That could be true as well - I'll update the question with this possibility.  Perhaps they have mailing lists that contain largely technical audiences, to give better results.  It certainly caught my attention, but way too many hallmarks of spam to be taken seriously.

Comment: Maybe it's a sinister plot by Jeff and Joel to advertise SO! ;) Not like it *needs* any advertising at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I would be extremely surprised if options 1 - 3 are actually true, consider the way Jeff and Joel feels about spam. I also doubt Jeff will take this lightly in any way whatsoever. The last thing SO needs is a reputation for spamming.

My best advise is to forward it on the the team at team@stackoverflow.com if you haven't already.

Comment: The database contains at minimum the questions and answers, and a lot of them have links to other sites so 1 could still be true without having a bot harvest websites directly from SO.  I don't know if the data dump SO provides has the full (visible) user profile, which would have more links to user's websites.

Comment: Perhaps your email address is in someone else's profile. Or in one of your answers.

Comment: I did a search for it, and it looks like it's not in any questions or answers, but my website is in a few questions and answers, and also in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

I actually received an email from someone who's question I answered. I never responded to it. He probably got my address off of my personal website which is linked in my profile. Check the web page that you specified in your profile for any contact information.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [harvest e-mails from Gravatar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21117/147191), which StackExchange uses. That could possibly be what happened.