# Is using Gravatar a security risk?

Tags: discussion, gravatar, security

This has been [discussed on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415/decode-email-address-from-gravatar-hash). It is unfortunate the accepted answer is so far from reality.

There are some facts:

- [Gravatar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravatar)'s MD5 hash is an unsalted MD5 hash of an email address.
- A 3rd party could harvest every MD5 hash for every user's email on Stack Overflow.
- The 3rd party could store all the hashes in a lookup table
- Email addresses are usually of a very particular format
- The attacker could start with a brute force of @gmail.com followed by @yahoo.com, etc.
- The attacker has the advantage that he/she could attack a huge set of emails in one go. So instead of needing to brute force every email individually the attacker can brute force in bulk.

  - The algorithm is quite simple, calculate a "random" MD5, look it up in the lookup table.

Is Gravatar a big enough security risk to warrant caching images locally?

Examples:

1. Someone could harvest about 50k email addresses quite easily and shoot off a bogus promotion from Stack Overflow to all the users.
2. A spammer/stalker/generic evil guy can tie you identity to all the rest of the sites that use Gravatar.

Comment: I've changed my gravatar to be associated with my first name. Reading your question makes me feel a bit more secure :)

Comment: I can see how this could possibly lead to more spam in your inbox. But how is that related to security?

Comment: Thought experiment, what if Jeff published email addresses in the data dump, would people be up in arms?

Comment: By the way, as a sort of side-issue, you could create an account at mailinator.com (it's not even creating an account really, just make up an id there) and use that here as your gravatar. Then it doesn't matter if someone emails you. Use an appropriately random string and life will be quite fine.

Comment: I thought gravatars were hashes of your IP address, not email...

Comment: Eric, your IP address is computer bound, not user bound. It changes ever so often, for example when you log in at another computer, a lot of internet provider even change the customers IP daily.  
Highly unpractical to use the IP for user identification.

Comment: oh god, if eric gets one more point he's going to go on a killing spree the likes of which we haven't seen since ff7.

Comment: @Eric - The IP address is used for posts by unregistered users who do not provide their email address when they post.  Otherwise the email address hash is used.

Comment: [Gravatar is now optional.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149436/support-disabling-gravatar-on-stack-overflow/161083#161083)

Comment: For anyone who cannot access the question that the author of this question linked to: http://web.archive.org/web/20140804033606/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415/decode-email-address-from-gravatar-hash

Answer (score 52):

I wonder how convenient is for a spammer to:

- Generate a possible email address
- Hash it
- See if it matches a known gravatar hash
- Send an email to it
- See if it bounces

instead of:

- Generate a possible email address
- Send an email to it
- See if it bounces

or ([Workshop Alex's approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/is-using-gravatar-a-security-risk/21125#21125)):

- Subscribe to technical mailing lists
- Grab the addresses from the emails
- Profit!

If you want addresses of programmers the last approach is much more economically viable. Supposing all you'd do is a brute force attack, you could even just grab the names from the profiles and try the second approach to get a similar list.

Privacy is a higher concern, but because you know you've signed to gravatar and you know at least it'll show up the same image everywhere you probably are conscious that you are giving some privacy up wherever you enter your email address.

Impersonation is the more worrying aspect of it and is not as easily solvable, in my opinion. But then again, it's not exclusive to gravatar, the additional component is that it will show your image. Anybody with or without gravatar can impersonate you at the same level if he knows your name and email address (that's why you use another auth mechanism.)

So, while I don't think this is a worrying thing that has to be fixed ASAP, it would be nice to have it fixed just in case with all this fuzz a spammer decides to give it a try :-)

Comment: You are able to get about 50k known valid email addresses without posing a single thing anywhere, its significantly more convenient and it does not burn you early.

Comment: For a spammer I doubt it matters to send 1000k emails than 100k emails. The payoff rate is so much higher.

Comment: Vinko, someone could target the stackoverflow audience with a promotional message from stackoverflow that is bogus, many people will not bother checking the email it came from

Comment: a) I doubt that's the case in SO and b) They could send the same targeted email to more addresses. Anyhow I suggest you reread the answer, I've edited it some :-)

Comment: All I'm saying is, would you feel comfortable if Jeff published your email address in the data dump ?

Comment: And all I'm saying is, this isn't exactly like Jeff publishing my email address in the data dump. Although to answer your question, I wouldn't mind much. I filter most (99.99%) of the spam, and I'd never (knock on wood) fall for a phishing attack

Comment: An offline modern laptop could check around 10,000,000,000 mail addresses an hour. I don't know how many e-mails could reasonably be sent (when online), but I'm guessing somewhat fewer.

Comment: As for *"Privacy is a higher concern, but because you know you've signed to gravatar [..]"* -- not everyone actually subscribes at Gravatar, but still many sites send the hashed email address to that site. That raises other privacy concerns; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/non-gravatar-avatar/5658#5658

Comment: @Tom: The problem is actually sending the email and handling bounces, not generating an address. @Arjan: Good point.

Comment: # Subscribe to technical mailing lists
# Grab the addresses from the emails
# Hash it
# See if it matches a known gravatar hash
# Generate more personalized mail
# Profit!

Comment: Because this question has been mentioned on Discourse lately, I'm going to add that a modern email may can send that many emails, but most mail gateways won't let you ;-)  And to answer Waffles: I wouldn't mind, my email address is all but evident for most everyone.

Answer (score 24):

To determine if something is a security risk, you'd also
have to consider it's popularity and the amount of
information a hacker would get considering the amount of
time he'll have to invest to get this information.

In general, a hacker could get access to a list of email
addresses. Are these valuable? Not really, unless the user
doesn't use a spam filter. Then you could spam the Hell out
of them. And perhaps you could collect a list of sites that
a person is visiting. In my case, StackOverflow and the
related sites. I don't use Gravatars anywhere else.

But collecting email addresses is much easier by just
subscribing to mailing lists, Google and Yahoo Groups and by
running a webspider over the Internet. Spammers are
harvesting million of email addresses this way and can
receive a lot more practical information than hacking into
Gravatars.

I did a test once, several years back, checking how easy it
is to harvest email addresses. I created a dozen Yahoo
accounts and subscribed every account to about 30 different
Yahoo groups. Yahoo still supported POP3 back then thus I
could use a POP3 client to read my emails. And I would use
this POP3 client to download all those emails to extract
just the email addresses. These were stored in a database
with a link to the account that discovered it plus
additional information about the email like title and the CC
list. It allowed me to discover a lot of information about
who was active where and how often and I could even detect
that some email accounts appeared to be linked to the same
person. (And it allowed me to create a list of spammers
which I could blacklist.)

The amount of information that I could collect this easily
made me much more aware of my online privacy. I didn't get
hundreds, or thousands of addresses... No, within a week I
had about 25,000 different email addresses! It took me two
months and some group switching to end up with ten times
more addresses.

So I don't fear hackers gaining information about my email
address through my Gravatar. They have a lot easier way to
harvest email addresses!

---

The scheme I used to find email addresses by subscribing to
mailing lists could even become more advanced. First you
start with a few accounts and subscribe to a dozen mailing
lists. As emails arrive, you can check these for email
addresses of even more mailing lists. This, because some
people are cross-posting their messages to multiple lists.
Furthermore, most people seem to forget about the BCC option
with email, which would hide all recipients. By detecting
more mailing lists this way, you could subscribe to even
more lists and create more accounts so no one notices that
you're in 500+ different lists.
Not only would you be able to harvest lots of emails this
way, you could even make a mapping of how different lists
are related to each other and check the interests of each
and every member, thus finding those members who might be
more susceptible for certain kinds of fraud. For example,
look at Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault. If these
sites were just plain mailing lists and some posts would
e.g. be crossposted to other lists then it's not too
difficult to find possible system administrators who work
for a company that uses Windows and VB webservices. If you
could cross-check these members with a list called
"hardCorePorn" and you find a few members that are part of
SO/SU/SF and this HCP group then you know which of these
members might be interested in opening an email offering
free porn that actually contains some malware with the
intent to infect their Windows servers. Even if only 1% of
those people are fooled, if you find 1000 administrators
then you can infect 10 sites with malware, and continue
harvesting information from there.

Information is extremely valuable, especially if you can
link them together. Even without the gravatar there's a big
risk that someone still manages to get your email address
from this site. Think of this: how many members here have a
username that's very similar to their email address? Would
Sam.Safron@yahoo.com be one? (Typing error in name made on
purpose, just in case I guessed correctly!) Or perhaps
WorkshopAlex@hotmail.com. (Nope!) With 90,000 users at
Stack Overflow, if only 1% uses a username identical to their
email address, plus @gmail, @yahoo.com or some other common
mail provider, then just collecting user names from SO could
already provide 900 email addresses! And of course, the
first user already has a reasonable easy email address. Last
name plus @provider. Fortunately, Jon Skeet doesn't use
Gmail. :-) Yet he mentions his email address inside his
profile so that's already one harvested address. Some
members will also add an URL to their personal site, though.
Jon does so too, and this additional information could have
been used if he hadn't posted his email address too! Last
name + @ + host of personal site = another harvested email
address...

Don't worry about how insecure certain techniques are. In
the end, the biggest security problem is the user himself,
not the technique.

Comment: In other words, even though it could be possible, I'm not worried because it's not worth the effort.

Comment: Yes, this is my point, you exemplified so much better. +2 if I could.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, I've thought about this as well, but there's another aspect you haven't addressed: privacy. With any site that uses Gravatar you can identify a user on one site as being the same as the user on another.

Comment: More importantly, you can trivially post as another user by using their email address (you don't need a password). So if you don't use a specifically private email address for you gravatar, it may be possible to find your regular email, and trivially impersonate you.

Comment: But the user knows he is consciously doing so when he signs up for gravatar, no?

Comment: That just makes me worry more :p This whole gravatar thing is a time bomb. Personally I care less if the evils get my email address, heck its on my blog and the spam is flowing. But, the whole concept of a big fat sweep of email addresses scares me somewhat.

Comment: @silky, are you saying that someone can post as me, if they only know my email. That would be a serious flaw in the system.

Comment: Sam: To be clear, *NOT ON THIS SITE*, but on another blog that implements it. Say on (IIRC) Phil Haacks site. If I know your email, I can trivially impersonate you there.

Comment: Yeah the whole anonymous blog posting thing is a real pain, I can also just steal your gravatar image and make a post look like it came from you on 99% of blogs

Comment: @cletus, I changed the question to community wiki, feel free to add the privacy concern as well

Comment: But you could do that from before gravatar, no? The only change is that now it appears with an image

Comment: Many blogs comment boxes promised **your email will not be published** but then went ahead in installing Gravatar, *publishing readers' faces*! http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/30605/11058

Answer (score 4):

On a time and resources trade-off it just would not be worth it for spammers to do this -

**Current mechanisms** for harvesting email addresses are pretty much 100% automated. Some spam list vendors charge more for fully validated lists, but it is known that there will always be a large proportion that are invalid at any time. Doesn't matter - it costs spammers nothing to send out emails to the list anyway.

**Trying to grab** email lists through matching gravatar hashes etc - not worth it.

**Collation of data** on which blogs you post to - okay this could be a worry for someone in a country where the political regime will punish you for visiting or posting on certain sites, sure, but for those of us not in those countries, everyone tracks this anyway. Are you up in arms about google analytics etc?

**Impersonating you on a blog** - so many ways to do it already, why bother making it difficult?

All in all, for an attacker it is a non-starter. There is no reward.

Comment: A big part of mailing(/spamming) is finding out if the addresses in your harvested/purchased lists are real - there are a great deal of "spamtraps" and old accounts (which become traps) in these lists.  The SO data dump provides a list of over a million MD5s of valid, current mailing addresses.

Comment: @threecheeseopera SO doesn't validate email addresses. You can anything that looks like an email address, at it will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced that your attack vector presents a beneficial trade-off of resources for targets to a potential attacker.  How much time are they going to spend computing possible targets when they could be pursuing more lucrative means?

In addition:

- Stack Overflow users are more tech-savvy than most (as others have pointed out).  The number of people who are going to even see your spam or phishing attempt is *far* lower than the general popluation.
- Stack Overflow uses OpenID, so there is no login screen to spoof, no password to steal. Even if someone falls for a Stack Overflow phishing e-mail, what information would the attacker gain?

You merely assert that this is an easy thing for someone to do, a "time bomb" to use your words, but you offer no profiling or statistical evidence to back up your claims.  Are you really surprised to be seen as maybe a little paranoid?  Get some hard data first, then we'll talk.

Comment: The could spoof the  most common openID login screens (the google, myopenid, and yahoo ones) so openID doesn't make it invulnerable. Just because it can be defeated by "defense by obscurity" doesn't make it not a problem.

Comment: @Macha: Each additional screen they spoof reduces their likelihood of success.  The fact that they have to spoof three logons and sitll may not have the right service significantly undermines their return on investment, which is my fundamental argument.  Unless you can demonstrate that it's trivial to extract e-mail information from gravatars (as I asked the OP to do), I maintain that nobody will find this kind of attack to be worth their while.  There are easier ways and more foolish userbases to make money from.