# How can I find users that I know from Facebook, Google+, etc. on the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, users, social-networking

How can I find users that I know from Facebook, Google+, etc. on the Stack Exchange network? Wouldn't this be fairly easy given the OpenID integration?

I know, this isn't a social networking site…

Comment: Related declined request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137668/search-user-by-email.

Answer (score 7):

> I know, this isn't a social networking site...

Which is exactly why Stack Exchange has no incentive to add this feature to the site. In short, Stack Exchange is about the *content*, not about the *people*.

People always have the option to link to their Stack Exchange profiles from their other social media profiles and you can find them that way.

Comment: The problem is that people don't generally link to their Stack Exchange profiles, and I'd like to see if they are members...  To me, the content of the people I know is likely important to me as well.  There is no way to see that if they don't post their profile....

Comment: And thanks for killing my reputation...

Comment: That last sentence suggests that you're taking a social-media-esque mindset toward SE. It's understandable that you're going to have a hard time with that, because the system is specifically designed (and intended) _not_ to work as a social media site - to emphasize content over people, and Q&A over discussion. Also, if other people don't link to their SE profiles from elsewhere, that's only a problem for _you_, not for them. They might have it that way intentionally, because they don't want their SE accounts to be discoverable from their other online presences.

Comment: (2 comments up) eh, don't worry, you didn't have any reputation here to lose yet.