# Why am I not seeing user avatars, but only a red-x no-image indicator?

Tags: support, gravatar

For some time now I am not seeing user avatars in IE8, but only the red-x no-image indicator.  This is actually occurring to me on all stack exchange sites.  Is there some setting I am unaware of?

Btw, I am able to see user avatars on FF.  And I do not have images turned off in IE, either.

Not sure if this is a meta-SO question or a SuperUser question, but here I am.

Comment: What do you get if you visit http://www.gravatar.com on IE8 (that's the website where the avatars are hosted)? Have you tried clearing your browser (IE's) cache?

Comment: When I visit gravatar.com everything is nominal.  No problem.  Clearing the browser's cache changes nothing.

Comment: Seeing gravatars is now a 5000+ rep feature only (:P)

Comment: Ha.  That was slightly amusing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely due to a security policy issue in IE: The page is an http URL but some (actually many) avatars are https URLs.

**Example:**

[The page of (a random) user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2208961/carnez-davis) - a non-secure http URL

This user has [this avatar image](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/93a72e2aa338c0aa936e6a3388ea4a70?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG) (at least at the time I'm writing this) - a secure https URL

On Firefox (and others) the page and the avatar image look fine. On IE - or maybe on SOME IEs, depending on the security settings - the avatar is a broken image because IE won't load the https-source into the non-secure page.

I have the same issue in IE 11, and since I hardly ever use IE my (browser security) settings are the default as Microsoft chose them.

**UPDATE:**

It seems my first guess was wrong - but maybe not entirely, so I'll leave it here.

The real problem seems to be IE **Tracking Protection**. For some reason downloads form gravatar are blocked, in the console you find message ["SEC7114" (link to a Microsoft explanation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/dn423949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When I disable tracking protection in IE the gravatar image loads just fine.

When you go to

```
C:\Users\[[USER]]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Tracking Protection
```

you'll find (text) files with the tracking protection data used by IE. In one of those files you'll find a line that

```
-d gravatar.com
```

More details about IE Tracking Protection lists [can be found here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/tracking-protection-list-internet-explorer). Use notepad++ or some other editor than standard MS Windows notepad.exe though, those files have Unix line endings!

[Here is the Microsoft page where IE users can install tracking lists from](http://www.iegallery.com/en-us/trackingprotectionlists). It is likely that it depends on which tracking lists are actually installed and enabled. I have found that gravatar is in at least one list that I installed, [the one from abine.com (link to the text list)](http://www.abine.com/tpl/abineielist.txt).

I also found [this Meta-Stackoverflow issue: "Is Gravatar a privacy risk?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/is-gravatar-a-privacy-risk).

Comment: Recent changes in Firefox affecting the handling of mixed content has made a lot of this type of issue pop up in systems I work on, this is probably the correct assessment.

Comment: @Chris - I've updated my answer, it seems it's the tracking protection and not a general security setting is to blame.