# Reverse engineer Gravatar to email

Tags: discussion, profile-picture

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is using Gravatar a security risk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/is-using-gravatar-a-security-risk)
>   [Is Gravatar a privacy risk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/is-gravatar-a-privacy-risk)

Since the Gravatar is generated based on the email address. Is it possible to determine a user's email address based on their Gravatar?

Comment: where is the duplicate question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The email addresses in Gravatar are [stored as MD5 hashes](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/). It's the same kind of one-way protection used in password storage.

Comment: But for avatars, the "password" might be much more easily guessed, and then validated against the hash. Like when assuming a display name might also be the user name at one of the main email providers.

Comment: @chrisay It's only used for passwords by incompetent programmers, because brute-forcing md5 is fast. And for the same reason it sucks when hiding email addresses too.