# Someone contacted me by email but my email is not public

Tags: discussion, support, email, security, email-addresses

Last week I got an email to my email address saying "I saw on Stack Overflow that you were interested in.." and the content of the question I asked.
The email suggested I'll star a bug \ feature request on chromium website. The request is totally legit and I don't mind it at all, my main concern is that my email is somewhat exposed on Stack Overflow.

I emailed this guy back and asked him where did he get my email address from, he replied with "I made a long list of folks to email to tell about the bug report, so I don't remember specifics of any of them."

I'm sure that I'll get a lot of responses here saying that stack keeps our emails private but, the facts are:

1. I never published \ used this email address on Stack Overflow beside my login.
2. My user name is short and unique for Stack Overflow. (I don't use it on other sites what eliminates the chance that a Google search will show my email address for a specific user.. I don't think someone will do a search for a 3 letters username and expect to find anything)
3. Googling my user name and my email address will return zero results.

Is it possible the Stack Overflow team using users emails for their own benefit?

I don't know how relevant that is but on this guy about.me site it says that he is an ex-Googler.

**Update:**

A grace period on the bounty has started so I'm adding here what I've got so far.
Even if my SO login email is buried somewhere in the stack pages (which I still doubt) finding it, as we all figured out, isn't an easy task. I don't think that someone on his right mind (besides us :) ) would waste more than a minute to find someones email for something that minor such as staring a bug.

Possible solutions:

1. There's a dead simple MD5 extractor that can revert any MD5 to its original string.
2. The person that emailed me gained some kind of access to the SO user list

I've forwarded the email, as requested, to one of the SO team, maybe that will help us solve this mystery.

**Update 2:**

One of the users in the comments (@Arjan):

> 2 hours ago I left a comment on one of his answers,*(he his referring
>   to the person who emailed me. He found his SO username)* to get his
>   attention for this very question, and now the whole answer is
>   gone.Okay, it was not a very good answer. But assuming he deleted
>   himself, he knows about this very question now, but he did not respond
>   -- yet

The comment above was written on the 24 of Nov. The user in question got his first 100 rep Association Bonus on meta on the 24 of Nov. He definitely saw the comment, deleted his answer, read this question and chose to ignore it.

**Update 3:**

You should all read hwlau answer which makes perfect sense and describes how vulnerable MD5 is and how people can use that to their advantage.

Comment: *"Is it possible the stackoverflow team using users emails for there own benefit?"* ... not really no. And if they would, it would be a pretty serious violation. So there must be another explanation.

Comment: I had a person who contacted and followed me through several of my public *and* private social profiles, going so far as to *guess* my email address that, while easy to guess, wasn't disclosed on my SO profile (and by guess I mean sending a dummy email first just to see if it worked), just so he could "chat". I found it disconcerting, to say the least.

Comment: I don't know if this is still the case but this could be related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/is-using-gravatar-a-security-risk

Comment: So you have never, at any point, published any information about you in your profile? No Blog URL, web site, social media profile?

Comment: What was the particular question he pointed to?

Comment: Maybe you forwarded a Stack Overflow newsletter at one point or another? (I don't use it myself, so I don't know if the newsletter contains your username).

Comment: @Marc-Andre It doesn't seem to be a Gravatar, so that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: No Gravatar, Never used Stack Overflow newsletter. This is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895922/how-to-load-remote-url-inside-sidebar

Comment: do you have [meta-tag:careers] account?

Comment: Nop. Don't know what that is.

Comment: The particular question might not be the issue. If you have identifying info in *any* question or answer, it's easily linked to that one through your profile. A single link to a bug tracker, personal repository, etc, is all it really takes. True, you'd need to be somewhat... persistent... to find it, but people be crazy.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're the only good person on the internet who likes things ... he might have narrowed it down like that. ;)

Comment: @Bart Best comment yet! :)

Comment: @Sha yes you do have Gravatar, it's still linked in [this account](http://superuser.com/users/168806/sha) of yours [and another one](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/9460/sha) - decoding one of those hashes will lead to your email address. (e.g. https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b43ef93617807e82407537ddffcea66b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG)

Comment: How simply/feasible/realistic is that @ShaWizDowArd? Any clue? Afaik, you could only really confirm if the address you're thinking of has a certain Gravatar. Not obtain the full email address from it.

Comment: @Bart from some reading it seems there are databases of gravatar hashes already cracked, probably cost some money to get access but they're available and they claim to have cracked 10% of Stack Overflow users email.

Comment: I'd say there has to be a more trivial explanation to all of this then. Going to such lengths to just get someone to star a bug/feature request for Chromium ...

Comment: @Bart guess we'll never know... :(

Comment: @Bart you crack me up lol. I won't post this person name but now I'm really curious if he got something to do with the stackoverflow team.

Comment: You can [always have a look](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) @Sha.

Comment: @Bart for some reason your last comment sent me notification  although the OP Sha commented after me. Bug?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nope, both match according to the rules. Only 3 characters are needed. [status-by-design]

Comment: It seems that he is not on the team. End of conspiracy theory #1

Comment: I have an idea how it *might* have happened, but I hesitate to confirm it here, since that would be another link to your account.

Comment: And there's no abstract way in which you could explain it? Is it for this OP only, or a general way?

Comment: This OP specifically. A personal project was posted(with dropbox link) on a different question. The project's header files just might contain something identifiable. A username that may be used elsewhere. A typical auto-inserted "Created by ..."

Comment: Not to say that it couldn't happen to anyone, so in that sense it could be generalized. Linking accounts on the internet isn't *usually* very hard if you have the patience to dig.

Comment: @Geobits Okay, that should give the OP something to go on. If it would have been a general issue I would have suggested you contact SO/SE, but that doesn't seem necessary in this case.

Comment: @Geobits To be honest the first thing I did was searching for links I posted and checked them. There are a few names there but nothing even related to the current email address. I must point out, I don't mind people sending me emails to my stack address or my personal address, It just bugged the hell out of me in terms of "how did he do it".

Comment: Yea, I found a username, but there was no way for me to tell if that was the name they were using. I did a simple google search for it, but came up short and didn't feel like pursuing it further. Just figured I'd mention it.

Comment: @yoda but it's Gravatar... isn't it?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Never mind... I forgot that the salting was only if it was IP based, not for emails.

Comment: Can you paste the full email contents?

Comment: Hi, I saw on stackoverflow that you were interested in a chrome sidebar. We filed a new request for it here that I hope you'll consider starring to build our case for it: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/xxx Thanks, xxx

Comment: Nop. Why do you ask?

Comment: Hmm... weird. I give up, starring this question for a followup! @yoda probably did his own searching and came up with a guess which you just disproved. :)

Comment: By the way, are you from the same country as I am? (mine is public in my profile :))

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes! Where did you found that?

Comment: @Sha that was easy. עוגת קרם שניט.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Lol.. cool. no yoda, no O

Comment: @Sha are you a chef by any chance?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I searched for one in my code ;). not related to the email on stackoverflow though..

Comment: @Geobits Yes but it is still no related to the current email.

Comment: @Sha Looks like you posted a YouTube video in answer to a question back in June, and in the description for the video is your a link to you Github account, which contains your email address. Could that explain it?

Comment: Mind posting the link to the question?

Comment: It's very hard to keep from leaking information about ourselves. Have a hard look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206968/recognized-selector-giving-me-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance). Should you have perhaps anonymized the user-agent string?

Comment: [Sure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16962043/969613), I can delete in a second if you like.

Comment: @JMK not me, it's just a video i've found on youtube

Comment: Ah, worth a try haha :)

Comment: Ha @AlEverett, that reveals a lot indeed.

Comment: And the email address he contacted you on is a GMail one @sha?

Comment: Does your email address begin `shawn.gragg`? Googling the user agent brings back [this](http://markmail.org/message/z7426vw42oywy5km#query:+page:1+mid:z7426vw42oywy5km+state:results) and filling in the captcha reveals it starts `shawn.gr...` and googling "Shawn McGraggerSoft" reveals a surname.

Comment: The email is on gmail, yes. I don't know who shawn.gragg is. Definitely not me. Btw, the email is not my first name or last, it's just a made up nickname @ gmail.com

Comment: @AlEverett No, that user agent was pasted from someplace else. Not related to me in any way.

Comment: Dammit. The "Sha" made it so tempting. Grr

Comment: @Sha - Is that your github account you linked to or another persons?

Comment: @TravisJ - See the comments under Mad Scientist's answer. Unless there is more than one?

Comment: @TravisJ Not my github. I don't have a github account with the email address in question.

Comment: @Sha - Did you ask a question on linkedin with the same text as one of your questions on stackoverflow?

Comment: Never asked a question there. My account there is with my personal data and personal email. Not related in any way to the email in question.

Comment: Even if my email is buried somewhere in the stack pages (which I still doubt) finding it, as we all figured out, isn't an easy task. I don't think that someone on his right mind (besides us :) ) would waste more than a minute to find someones email for something that minor as starting a bug. This is what I got so far: 1. There's an easy "Email from Gravatar Extractor" we are not aware of (i'll mention again that my email is not a dictionary word). 2. That person can access stack users email. I can't think of another solution.

Comment: @Sha maybe he just guessed? E.g. `sha.stackoverflow@gmail.com` and similar combinations?

Comment: Another thing comes to mind... you said he worked in Google and that you're using gmail. So maybe he has access/backdoor to *their* database!!

Comment: There's no way he could have guessed. It would be like guessing kjhdfigjuij. The email is not even similar to my username. I thought about the googler option but How would he know where to look if all the info he got on me is my 3 letters user name?

Comment: Not really, I never cheat on Stack..:) He linked to a question I asked on stack..

Comment: OK, this is really weird. Several people have tried their Google- and other fu on this and came up with nothing, right? And the "cracking the gravatar hash" theory sounds super unlikely.

Comment: Today was the first time I've heard about the Gravatar MD5 thing so I'm not really sure if that is even possible. I've spend a respectable amount of time trying to fetch my email from my stack data without success, you can see in the comments that others gave it their best shot too.

Comment: I fear the only way will be to plainly ask the guy who wrote you "How did you find my email?" again, not taking "I made a list" as answer. He may or may not answer but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @Sha Hmm... does the nick "vlerow" mean anything to you?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I doubt that there's anything legit in the way he got my email, there's no way he'll come forward. Don't know what vlerow is..

Comment: Maybe I'll send him a link to this question saying "So... a lot of people are wondering...." ;)

Comment: Sending him a link sounds good, plus maybe email the team his user name so they can dig up in his activity. (assuming he got account on SO :))

Comment: I'm not sure I want to keep interacting with that person..I don't mind sending his email \ stack user name to the team if they ask me to.

Comment: Oh, you could have asked... 50 rep for you is a lot I wouldn't mind spending even 500, I'm as curious as you are! (well, almost :))

Comment: I had no idea you got rep to spare! Rep doesn't come easy this days :) I hope the bounty will help this question get more attention from the right people.

Comment: Some time ago, you used a name with initials M.S. on these sites. Could that be enough for a Google employee to find your Gmail address? (As you said the Gmail address is not your first name or last name, and is only 7 letters while the M.S. is 9 in total, I did not find a MD5 match for a Gmail address using that name. Using part of the M.S. plus "sha" yields an existing Gmail address, but I cannot quickly find a MD5 match for that either. Also, searching for that name *might* indicate on Instagram you're a cat lover, but that doesn't give me a MD5 match either...)

Comment: @Arjan Lol. I have no idea what M.S stand for, don't know where you guys seen it bet that's defiantly not my name initials or related to the email. I'm also not a cat lover so that's not my account..

Comment: That's weird... Your Stack Overflow id 1578927 [clearly shows that name was used in 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20121223044130/http://stackoverflow.com/users/1578927/mika-stern). (Another user with same avatar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2010268/mika-stern)). Also, using that name along with *stack overflow* in a Google search will make Google show chat history with your current avatar, and even shows your current account. (I had the same with my full name: for a very long time Google kept showing my SO account in the search results, loooong after I removed my last name.)

Comment: (If the M.S. name just slipped your mind, and you need my last comment to be removed, then just shout.)

Comment: @Arjan That name did slipped my mind. That was the first name this account was given (just a random name without any meaning). Unfortunately this still doesn't solve the mystery on how that guy got my email address that also got nothing to do with the name above.

Comment: I'm tempted to post here the email account in question. Surely that will ease the search and maybe help my curiosity.. I guess I'll save it as last resort.

Comment: Does the one who contacted you have more than 10k reputation? Then they can see deleted posts. (Though it still isn't easy to *find* such posts.) Any chance a deleted post of yours had more details?

Comment: (Ah: no, they are just below 3k reputation, so that can't be it either.)

Comment: I'm guessing it wasn't too hard to find him ha? :)

Comment: Hmmm, no he was not hard to find, especially as he also left related comments and answers getting attention from others on SO. Now, two funny things. Why didn't he simply leave a comment for you too -- was it really *that* easy to get your email address? And: 2 hours ago I left [a comment](http://i.stack.imgur.com/11cXG.png) on one of his answers, to get his attention for this very question, and now the whole answer is gone. Okay, it was not a very good answer. But assuming he deleted himself, he knows about this very question now, but he did not respond -- yet...?

Comment: This is getting stranger by the minute

Comment: Sha, is your name שיימוביץ ?

Comment: I wish! but no..

Comment: Perhaps the user who contacted you will be lured in by the tasty-looking bounty and will answer this question himself ;)

Comment: Read the comment Arjan wrote. There's a good chance he knows about this question and chooses to ignore it.

Comment: This is intriguing - would you forward the offending email to jarrod@stackoverflow.com please?  No one outside the technical staff will see it.

Comment: @harpz1970 yeah, http://www.sajmovic.com/207764/%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-1 was one of my first findings but I ruled it out quickly. :)

Comment: @sha please use `@` to reply, people don't get notified of your replies here and might not check manually. For example by writing `@harpz1970` before I caused notification to reach the user.

Comment: Vania Pelazzi is this Hanky Panky?

Comment: @JarrodDixon Email sent

Comment: This is like reading an exciting book :)

Comment: @Arjan I did a bit of investigating my self. The user you left a comment too on the 24 of Nov got his first 100 rep Association Bonus on meta, guess when? on the 24 of Nov. He definitely saw your comment, deleted his answer, read this question and chose to ignore it.

Comment: Maybe he's planning a new career for you with his new business ;-)

Comment: I'm not holding my breath. :)

Comment: Is your `na.....@gmail.com` address used for the Gravatar? And if yes: do you think you might have used the same email address elsewhere? Maybe he's collecting email addresses and simply compared hashes then, rather than trying to reverse-engineer the hash. (Which is one of the reasons why [I don't like Gravatar and services like that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/can-we-use-non-gravatar-avatars/5658#5658).)

Comment: The gravatar is using the email I signed up to SO. He's an ex google employee , maybe he MD5 all the emails he came across? .. Sounds crazy.

Comment: But did you only use that address on Stack Exchange? (As for being an ex-Googler: I truly doubt someone would be stupid enough to take such database from their previous employer, if one would have access to it to start with. But again, such would indeed make it much easier to get an address based on a hash, when the address is not related to one's username. And not simply leaving a comment instead of sending an email, and now not responding to the questions, is very odd too...)

Comment: I'm sure I've used it on other places but not something that will tie it to my SO username without a really massive deep psychopathic Google search. I doubt he got my email using search. It must have been a click & find solution. The fact that he chose to ignore this question...

Comment: `1.There's a dead simple MD5 extractor that can revert any MD5 to its original string.` That is no `dead simple` stuff.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Dead simple in a way that it's just an app you open, submit your MD5 and get a string. I wasn't referring to the algorithm behind it..

Comment: @MD5 is one way hashing for 99.99% of the people. No de-hashing there for most

Comment: Unless, @Hanky, such dead simple app somehow has a huge list of email addresses, somehow captured earlier, and can match on that hash. Of course, we all know that the chances are very low. But in case you missed it in the comments: the one who emailed Sha simply used comments to address some other people on Stack Overflow. So it must be something simpler than commenting? (And he's an ex-Googler who now co-founded a startup that advertises giving recruiters *"a complete view"* of candidates. Maybe, just MAYBE, they have been collecting lots of email addresses and other data for that.)

Comment: Sha, curious: did the email also include your full name, or only your email address? (In Gmail, when reading a message, there's a dropdown menu next to the reply button, which includes "Show original". There you'll find the "To:" header which does NOT include one's full name when not explicitly set when composing the message. Even when sending from Gmail to Gmail, in which case Gmail itself would know the recipient's full name, it's not there unless the sender added that full name. Of course, your name could also have been used in the message itself.)

Comment: @Arjan The "To:" didn't include my name.

Comment: @Arjan Do you remember how many comments with the same msg he left on SO? All those comments are already deleted.

Comment: The screenshot I took *after* that answer was deleted [showed 7](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n2QoW.png). So, 7 or more.

Comment: Cool that you were smart enough to take a screenshot. I've updated my question with some of the great info you contributed to this question.

Comment: Too bad I didn't hover one of the dates, to see a timestamp on that screenshot. The (deleted) answer [was posted November 16, 16:51 UTC](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YVDMt.png). Just curious again: was that before or after getting the email?

Comment: After. The email was sent on Fri, 15 Nov 2013 10:09:57 -0800 (PST)

Comment: This might me highly irrelevant but in the email source the Return-Path and Sender field are full.name.name@gmail.com while the From field is firstname@fullname.com . I'm guessing that's forwarding related and not a very interesting detail but thought I'll just trow it in here.

Comment: No updates? This has had me on the edge of my seat for weeks!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I'm also very disappointed. I thought that I'll get an update after mailing jarrod from the SO team but never heard from him.

Comment: Interesting read: [Crypto weakness in Web comment system exposes hate-mongering politicians -- Journalists exploit weakness in Gravatar to identify extremist forum members](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/12/crypto-weakness-in-web-comment-system-exposes-hate-mongering-politicians/). (Thanks to [D.W.'s comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/is-gravatar-a-privacy-risk/79856?noredirect=1#comment679387_79856).)

Comment: AAHHH so was not resolved by Chris' answer? This is like a gripping series that gets cancelled, only to then find renewed funding

Comment: @Arjan Great read. Thanks for the bounty!

Comment: The MD5 explanation doesn't convince me. Sure, it's possible, but is it *likely*? Especially as the person in this case didn't offer you a job or 25 million dollars, but asked you to *star a bug?* Meh.

Comment: @Pëkka No job offer (Yet!).. I'd imagine, though, that if you'll have a certain tool you use for work you might use it from time to time for personal use. If such a list exists I'm sure I wasn't the main target but all the other SO members. I'm not 100% convinced but it's the most logical explanation suggested here.

Comment: @Jarrod, just curious (*very* curious): did your investigation of the forwarded email reveal anything? (By now I think that the NSA was involved! Or Elvis.)

Comment: More conspiracy :-) He once forked an entry of the [Multicultural Person Name Matching challenge](https://github.com/dbyrne/NameMatching): *"Uses include verifying eligibility for Social Security or medical benefits, identifying and reunifying families in disaster relief operations, vetting persons against a travel watchlist, and merging or eliminating duplicate records in databases. [...] can also be used to improve the accuracy and speed of document searches, social network analysis, and other tasks in which the same person might be referred to by multiple versions or spellings of a name."*

Comment: @JarrodDixon over a month later, any update? Many users here are curious and/or alarmed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on an extended vacation (and that blasted topbar rollout :), but I've been running queries on our logs.  Getting input from other team members as their vacation schedules allow.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Great to hear that this issue is not ignored. Have fun! We'll be waiting patiently for any updates.

Comment: Still no job offer for you? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Not yet.. Recently I added some great answers on stack, I have no idea what's going on with him!. ;)

Comment: Another month has passed.. Any news on this @JarrodDixon ?

Comment: At least [new datadumps no longer include the hash](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221027/where-did-emailhash-go).

Comment: Just for future reference: D.W. edited two more examples of reverse engineering the MD5 hash into [Is Gravatar a privacy risk?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/is-gravatar-a-privacy-risk/79856#79856).

Comment: As for Google employees having access to data, Google wrote in 2010 when a "Site Reliability Engineer" was fired [after snooping through account data](http://gawker.com/5637234/gcreep-google-engineer-stalked-teens-spied-on-chats): *"We carefully control the number of employees who have access to our systems, and we regularly upgrade our security controls–for example, we are significantly increasing the amount of time we spend auditing our logs to ensure those controls are effective."*

Comment: Okay, this took some time ;-) [Preview: A ToS update restricting companies that scrape your profile information without your permission](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/preview-a-tos-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-information). And, go, run, hide, LinkedIn [has purchased that guy's company two months ago](https://blog.connectifier.com/connectifier-to-join-linkedin/)... And for good laughs, that company [does not want to be in the Internet Archive](https://www.connectifier.com/robots.txt). Well, [bad luck](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o4RZ2.jpg).

Comment: Well what do you know.. I can't say I'm surprised though. Great research work @Arjan . A really strange story I must say. What still bothers me is that we didn't got a formal statement \ apology from Stackoverflow about all that leaked data. Also, I wonder about the legality of this issue. Can they still use all the scraped data?

Comment: Okay, let go already, Arjan. ;-) [Get personal email addresses and 
boost engagement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSv49.jpg). ([Source](https://business.linkedin.com/talent-solutions/recruiter/connectifier).)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The user that contacted you performed a search, found your question, then visited your user page.  He had no other contact with any of your other content.  That's all the information our logs show.

As others have said, it's possible the user has access to an MD5-to-email lookup.   To mitigate the ease of obtaining gravatar hashes, we've already removed them from data dumps and [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com), and we're working on a solution for the remaining places the hashes are exposed (i.e. on the sites themselves and their apis).

Comment: (Just in case it helps you and you missed it: the email was sent on Fri, 15 Nov 2013 10:09:57 -0800 (PST). I'm curious how much time passed since visiting Sha's profile, but I understand that's not information you'll make public.)

Comment: @Arjan I'm also very curious about this. I don't see why Jarrod won't post it here.

Answer (score 94):

Here's one way they could have done it.

I was able to link you to a GitHub account based on a Dropbox link you posted (with a quick Google to make the connection). From there, I cloned your repository and your email address was visible in the raw Git commit data.

I also found a MozillaZine account, but I couldn't find any Chromium bug tracker connections.

To respect your privacy, I won't be any more specific (unless you ask otherwise).

Someone *really* wanted to talk to you (or maybe they found an easier way).

Comment: Surprising how easy it is...

Comment: If it explains the mystery: Wow, good job

Comment: You sir, deserve at least one internet. Failing that, have an upvote

Comment: ...oh, and by 'easy', I don't at all mean to belittle the cool effort you did here!

Comment: I am _never_ making this guy angry.

Comment: @Chris I've found the GitHub connected to the dropbox link. Unfortunately that doesn't solve the mystery. I don't have a GitHub account with the email in question. You are still getting +1 for outsmarting us all ;) The email should start with "na".

Comment: @Sha Ah, ok. Yeah, the GitHub account was under a Gmail address.

Comment: @Chris the email in question is also under gmail but like I said starts with na.

Comment: Also note that he left the very same message to other users on SO by just leaving a comment (and even posting an answer, which basically also was a comment, and meanwhile has been deleted -- see comments on the question above). And commenting is so much easier than even *thinking* about cloning a repo. In other words: he must have an easier way?

Answer (score 29):

The situation mentioned by @D.W. is very true. A simple calculation below suggests that all emails with less than 11 characters must be cracked, and I will give a motivation to do so.

The data dump here already contains all the MD5 hashed emails and the corresponding userid. Hence, it would be possible to do a brute force matching and there are someone do has hundreds GPU hanging around. Suppose each top GPU could have 1GHash/s, and there are 100 GPU, and run for 3 days. It gives total `H = (10^9 * 100 * 3 * 86400) ~ 2.6*10^16 hash`.
Also, assuming the character set are only letters (no capital), numbers and some symbols which accounts for at most 40 letter, so `log(H)/log(40) = 10.25`

It means that all emails with 10 or less characters from major email providers must be cracked already with brute force. Provided you have the equipments, it is easy to do and it requires very low technical skills compared with the "advance skills" like dictionary attacked (which should be harder to parallelize in GPU, I guess). Definitely, more can be cracked if they spend more time, but the basic one is really just hours of setup.

About the motivation, someone might find it fun to do it, but it does cost their time and money to run the equipments. So if they can sell dozens of the userid<->emails list, it would a good motivation. The list might have various use. In particular, with the price and restriction on career.stackoverflow, such a simple list would be very handle for the companies bypassing the system and directly contacting with the candidates. There are various email lists out in the wild and the person using it might not even know where it is from. Also, most of users being contact would not notice that it is leak from here as their emails are likely being reused. Anyway, my point is such list is easy to create and there is enough motivation to do so.

Even though the stack keep saying that emails are private, but they already release the email list, in an easily decoding MD5 which they don't even salt it.

---

**Edit**: It could have been harder and make this attempt infeasible if the data dump contains salted md5 hash, which requires attempting one email at a time so my above estimation is for one email only. But with the unsalted hash, the GPU only need blind hashing all combinations and send the results back to CPU which then compares all user emails at once. So it is faster by the factor of #users and make the extraction feasible. The limitation would be memory bandwidth which I did not include in my estimation, but the results only slow down few times depending on hardwares.

Comment: *"with the price and restriction on career.stackoverflow, such a simple list would be very handy for the companies bypassing the system and directly contacting with the candidates"* -- and in case you missed it: the sender's startup is indeed about some website to match candidates with jobs...

Comment: @Arjan Yup, I don't know the details, I am just speculating here. My point is that I believe everything that is possible, motivated and easy would be done by someone. The easier, the more people will do that.

Comment: @Arjan: I thought they claimed it was just for some feature request on a bug tracker?

Comment: Indeed, the email to Sha and the comments to other people at Stack Overflow were about a bug report, @Chris. However, the author of that email and those comments is a co-founder of a startup company that advertises giving recruiters *"a complete view"* of candidates... That, plus his silence here though he surely knows we're wondering how he got the email address, makes me quite suspicious. But no proof at all, of course. Could be something else for sure.

Comment: @hwlau It all adds up. If its that easy like hwlau describes it makes perfect sense. Scanning the SO db and extracting all the MD5 you can find then use all the CPU\GPU power you have to crack those up and end up with a gigantic list of programers emails (perfect job candidates) I can imagine that that list is worth a LOT of money. On the way i'll promote a bug report I care about. I don't have that user MD5...I'll just comment to his question....I don't have that user MD5...I'll just comment to his question....I have Sha MD5 on my list, cool, I'll just email him instead.

Comment: But why would someone use such a valuable list to ask for upvotes in a bug database?

Comment: Imaginary internet points are really important to people, didn't you know?

Comment: @Joe "Earned ten of the most meaningless points on the 'Net" -  Shog9♦

Comment: No proof f course, I'm not accusing anyone.. We are just speculating here.. I'm just saying that after reading all the info here, specially this answer and then reading the first title of this guy startup page...it all feels too suspicious.

Comment: @Pëkka: Maybe the whole reason he was contacting people was to verify the email addresses, before selling them to recruiters. (If Arjan's guess is correct, then this might make sense).

Comment: Or, @Pëkka, simply because he didn't realize he was exposing having such list? (*If* there is such list, of course.) If I would have created such list, I would also have created a user script to easily find me the email address when just clicking any gravatar. Or maybe a script to show the email address next to a gravatar, and then at some point forgetting that it was not public information I was looking at...

Comment: (In case you missed it, @Pëkka, I'm worried by that guy's startup company promising recruiters *"a complete view"* of candidates, *and* that guy [not responding here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/11cXG.png) but cleaning up his answers/comments instead. Hoping there's a much simpler explanation...)

Comment: Ah: since November Stack Exchange is [salting creation of hashes for generating identicons for users that do not have a gravatar account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204523/unexpectedly-changing-identicon/204540#204540). (So the old datadumps are becoming valuable, *if* hashes were used to get email addresses. But then, @Sha *does* have a Gravatar account, so the hashing is is not related to this very question.)

Comment: @Arjan What makes you say that I have a Gravatar account? I don't remember signing up for one.. I thought the Avatar pics I got on other SE websites are something default that the system gives to any user that doesn't upload a picture.

Comment: @Sha, my bad: I somehow forgot about the option to upload an image to SE. So when I saw that your avatar here on Meta is clearly not some generated identicon, I boldly assumed you uploaded a custom image to a Gravatar account... (Which is stupid to think, as I am using the SE upload function myself as well, with a slightly altered Gravatar identicon.) As an aside, after re-reading [Unexpectedly changing identicon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204523/unexpectedly-changing-identicon): *maybe* the hashes for identicons are only salted as soon as one clicks the link to change the image.

Comment: @Arjan Maybe.... I'll emphasize what I said on another comment. It all comes down to that one title sentence on that company page that changed my point of view completely. I wish that the SO team will respond \ acknowledge this alarming issue.

Answer (score 25):

The mail address in your profile is private, only mods and SE employees can see it and they are not allowed to share it with third parties. Sharing PII like mail addresses is covered by the moderator agreement, and each access to that information is logged as well. SE doesn't sell mail addresses or something like that as far as I know.

The usual way someone gets your email address if it isn't published in your profile is by correlating your account with another one that has the mail associated. If your user profile contains enough information to identify you, the mail address could then be taken from your Twitter or Facebook account or any other source that can be somehow connected to your account.

In your specific case I can't actually see how this would have worked, though. I don't see enough personal information in your profile.

Comment: Whilst true in the general sense, this user's profile has very little identifying information. A short meaningless username, no website, no location, nothing personal in the bio.

Comment: @Matt I just added that as I noticed it as well

Comment: Maybe something he reveal in one of his question. He said : `and the content of the question I asked.`

Comment: I started my profile a while back and to my recollection never posted anything personal on my profile. This is the question the email referred to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895922/how-to-load-remote-url-inside-sidebar

Comment: @Sha The Github link contains your full name

Comment: If that is him, and he's not simply using the code @MadScientist.

Comment: @Matt That's just someones repository, I was just using his code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The OP explicitly states in the comment above yours that it's not him. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bart: I missed that comment.

Answer (score 24):

There are some technical aspects of the Stack Exchange platform that could, at least in principle, allow someone to deduce your email address.  I somehow doubt that it's what happened to you, but I'll document it here for posterity, since I haven't seen it written down anywhere else.

In particular, the MD5 hash of your email address is made publicly visible in data dumps and via Data Explorer (e.g., try [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/148430/)).  Moreover, for many people it will be possible to recover your email address, given its MD5 hash.  For many people, their email address has relatively low entropy: there are a handful of common options for the domain name, and one can enumerate many common possibilities for the username (one can also use your profile and your StackExchange username to help seed candidates for the username).  This provides a large list of candidate email addresses for you.  Then, one can use offline dictionary search to test each one against the known MD5 hash, to see if any of those have the same MD5 as your known MD5 hash.  Due to the improvements in use of GPUs for password cracking, there are existing tools for this sort of MD5 reversing that are surprisingly efficient.  Based upon past analyses, I would expect that many (but not all) users could have their email address recovered.

I haven't seen any place that publicly discloses this risk.  I learned about it on a post I made to MSO a while ago that has since been auto-deleted.

That said, while this is technically *possible*, I don't know whether it's likely that anyone will bother to go to these lengths just to learn your email address.  They'd have to download a MD5 cracker, configure it to help it generate plausible email addresses, tweak it by hand, and leave it running for hours.  That doesn't sound super-plausible to me.

Bottom line: my expectation would be that there's some other explanation -- that this is not the cause of the email you got.  However, I suppose it's possible, in theory.

Comment: Like I said in the comments, I doubt that someone made that effort just to get my email plus my email isn't a dictionary word.. still, you wrote some great information here that I wasn't aware of. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that the spammer got hands of the mail from somewhere else and calculated the md5 hash of each adress.

Comment: It wasn't a spammer, @Johannes. It was a legit request referencing a specific SO question (that's what's so weird)

Comment: Please merge this with your [other answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207912/145951) as much of it overlaps.

Answer (score 16):

Due to a technical weakness in the gravatar system, *if* you use an auto-generated Gravatar, in many situations it would be technically possible to derive your email address from the Gravatar you use.  Whether anyone will go to the lengths necessary to do so is less clear, but it is technically possible.

Here's how.  The URL to your Gravatar contains a MD5 hash of your email address in the URL. There is no salt in the MD5 hash, so it is possible to do a dictionary attack: guess many possibilities at your email, and test each one to see whether it is correct.  If your email address is guessable (and many people's email addresses are), then this would be one way that someone could learn your email address, if you use the default the Gravatar.

I once wrote a [detailed technical explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191827/160917) of this on Meta.StackOverflow, but it looks like the question was deleted (some folks took exception to my characterization of this as a privacy weakness or felt it was covered by prior discussion and downvoted the question, so it ended up with a total score of -2: +11 upvotes, -13 downvotes; as a result it eventually got auto-deleted by the Community user), so you won't be able to read it unless you have > 10K rep on MSO.  You can find a less detailed explanation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21117/160917), but that post is old, so it doesn't take into account the potential for GPU-based dictionary attacks, which potentially change the risk calculus, and it misses some relevant links and analysis.

If I recall correctly, I believe this *only* applies to people who use the default auto-generated Gravatar.  If you upload your own avatar image, it doesn't apply to you.  It looks like you currently have a custom avatar image, so assuming this is not something new for you, I suspect this doesn't apply to you and so probably wasn't the way they got *your* email address.  But I'm just trying to document this for posterity, in case anyone else runs across this situation.

Comment: Although I don't use a Gravatar on Stackoverflow (as people mentioned in the comments) I have a default Gravatar on stack design and other stack sites I used once or twice. But, my email address is not a dictionary word so I'm assuming you'll need one hell of a brute force attack to discover it.. Doing all that just to get someones email? Idk..

Comment: Yeah.  Agreed, @Sha.  Sounds pretty implausible -- doesn't seem very likely to be what's going on in your situation...

Comment: @Sha It doesn't matter if the gravatar is default or not. Merely using it is enough to leak the hash. Back in 2011 I ran a cracker on those hashes, and recovered [27k](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84734/152255)

Comment: @CodesInChaos How much time do you think it would take to crack my hash to find my email address? (I'm just curious if that is really the way that guy got my email address)

Comment: @Sha The main issue with cracking is obtaining the word lists and configuring the cracker. For somebody who is into password cracking this is pretty easy, for others it's probably several hours of work. The cracker then attacks all hashes at the same time. It'll find many email addresses within the first few hours, and then become slower and slower. If your address would be among the cracked depends on how guessable it is, and how good the dictionary used by the cracker is.

Comment: @CodesInChaos And if the email is something like aijdjfvjjf@gmail.com Is that even possible to crack using just the hash?

Comment: @Sha If it doesn't contain any patterns (yours does), 10 chars have 52 bits of entropy. This is outside of the range I tried with my CPU cracker, but with a GPU cracker it might be possible. With a slightly shorter name or by exploiting patterns it becomes even cheaper. That said, it's pretty unlikely that somebody bothered to brute force 10 characters to recover your email.

Comment: Very interesting. What makes you say that mine contains patterns? It only contains 7 chars btw.

Comment: Please merge this with your [other answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207914/145951) as much of it overlaps.