# "Hello from Google" Spam or no?

Tags: discussion, email

I received this curious e-mail (just noticed it, I haven't logged in a while), and wrote it off as spam. But after googling it, it seems people have received similar [unsolicited](https://pthree.org/2007/05/27/why-blog-because-google-might-hire-you/) [e-mails](http://dohnutland.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/how-i-got-a-recruitment-letter-from-google-without-even-trying/) [from google](http://www.schabell.org/2007/10/hello-from-google.html) (search `Hello from Google` for more examples.) While I realize this is probably off-topic, I was curious if anyone has received a similar e-mail, especially since this one mentions my StackOverflow account.

[image]

---

The person finally replied:

> Hi Remy,
>
> No problem, thanks for getting back to me and I'm glad to have amused
>   you :)
>
> Apologies for the error in contacting you, as I mentioned I found your
>   details on StackOverflow and saw that were a top user of C++ so
>   thought it would be worth dropping you an email to find out a bit more
>   about your experience.
>
> If you are interested in hearing about opportunities at Google
>   (perhaps in other areas!) then feel free to send me your resume and I
>   can forward to the relevant colleague.

Comment: This is a purely pragmatic comment and not meant to insult you in any way, but 500 rep is not a lot on Stack Overflow, and anyone who thinks  it is is probably pulling your leg.

Comment: The person really works at Google (though it could be a fake person).

Comment: I can check if the person is real or not... gimme a sec. (edit: The person is real. She's a Google employee.)

Comment: @Mysticial See my comment above..., the name works at Google, though could be a fake person sending the email.

Comment: @TheGrinch I'm not insulted at all, I just found this to be interesting and it would be a hell of a coincidence to receive a random e-mail from a Google employee, spam or not.

Comment: @TheGrinch well, he does appear in the [top users list](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/topusers) for [tag:c++].

Comment: @TheGrinch Bounties... But that doesn't make your point any less valid.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: So do I, and I've not written a line of C++ code since the early '90s. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: So do I, and I've never written a C++ program. :O

Comment: Anyhow back to topic, I'm 99% sure it's pure spam and that many emails of Stack Overflow have been "harvested" at some point through Gravatar before Stack Exchange added more salt. Spammers buy those emails, check the top users per tag and send such emails. Scary! As for the name appearing as Google employee, it's totally trivial for anyone to send email that will appear to come from "God All Mighty" and even change the "reply-to" email. What really matters is the server from which the email was sent.

Comment: @ShadowWizard In this case, the email address and the person are both valid. (I'm a Google employee so I can look up other employees) So I'm pretty sure the email is legit unless it had a spoofed sender.

Comment: @Mysticial I'll bet $1000 on spoofed sender.

Comment: @remyabel click the little arrow next to the "to me" in the email. What you see in the "mailed-by" field?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, I appear in the [top users](http://history.stackexchange.com/tags/human-sacrifice/topusers) for [human-sacrifice](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-sacrifice). Where's my recruitment e-mail?

Comment: @Yannis maybe you never used Gravatar, maybe your email was too long (only 8 character emails were hacked as far as I remember), maybe they don't care about that tag. ;-)

Comment: @remyabel one last try on this... can you please click "Show original" and post what you see after "Received"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hm, when was Gravatar hacked? I do use it, and my email is 6 chars long (can you guess what it is?).

Comment: @Yannis the Church of Satan will be with you shortly.

Comment: @Yannis unconfirmed of course, but it was published somewhere, yes. So maybe only emails *exactly* 8 characters long. Dunno.

Comment: @SHadowWizard `Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of REDACTED@google.com designates ... as permitted sender) client-ip=...;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of REDACTED@google.com designates ... as permitted sender) smtp.mail=REDACTED@google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@google.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=google.com`. Is this even helping any?

Comment: @Pëkka Oh, they already contacted me, right after I got a diamond on Politics.

Comment: @Yannis lol ----

Comment: @remyabel If you're really wondering whether the email is real or not, just send a response to the email address that you see.

Comment: @remyabel wish I knew, but surely there are those who can confirm by that if it was really sent from Google servers. Anyway if it's really from Google you can sew them for spamming and go public with it. Spam is spam, no matter who sends it. You never agreed to get such emails.

Comment: @Shadow I don't see how this is spamming at all. It's an initial reaching out to a publicly available address.

Comment: @Pëkka publicly available how? I don't see "Please send me job offers [here]" in the about me section. This **is** spam.

Comment: @Sha I assume Remy is linking to his SO profile somewhere where he has published his E-Mail address. (This is not about Google sniffing E-Mail addresses or something like that, right?)

Comment: @Pëkka even so, it does not give anyone the right to send him such emails. There is anti spam laws in some countries, exactly for those cases.

Comment: @Sha show me one successful lawsuit anywhere against someone who contacted someone else over a possible job. Spam is, by definition, *mass* email which this incident was not.

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207872/someone-contacted-me-by-email-but-my-email-is-not-public

Comment: That's a different discussion though. Or is the question here how the supposed Google person got your E-Mail address in the first place, @remy?

Comment: @Pëkka let's agree to disagree... personally I would flag such email as spam on spot and if I had the time and money for good lawyer would also go to court. As for different discussion you're right that's why related and not dupe, I just noticed his email isn't showing anywhere so assumed it's also a concern.

Comment: @Pekka No, my e-mail is clearly visible on my profile. For reasons stated in the top comment and suspicion that it is spam, I went here to see if anyone has received similar e-mails before I considered sending a reply or blowing it off.

Comment: @remyabel FWIW, That email you got is pretty typical not just for Google, but for a lot of companies. I got my current job at Google through an almost identical process. Somebody at Google sent me a similar email. I followed through on it and got the job. You seem to have received one of such emails. It's up to you to decide what you want do with it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Why bother spoofing the sender? You won't get any replies and there aren't any phishing links to click that I can see. (except possibly for a windup but the headers look legit)

Comment: @MartinSmith OK... I stand corrected. Guess I was overreacting for some reason I don't really understand myself.

Comment: @Pëkka /cc see comment to Martin

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nah it does seem to be a legitimate e-mail (they auto-replied saying the person is out of their office until January.) In the end I've decided to send a joke reply and be done with it. I don't think I'm Google material. :P

Comment: @remyabel well, you can do Stack Exchange a favor by replying and asking Google to go through the proper channels of [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), that's how companies should recruit Stack Overflow users.

Comment: @codehorse I agree, see my reply to Martin above.

Comment: @remy re being Google material - I remember Jon Skeet saying once that pretty much everyone there thinks they were the one lucky person who got in somehow despite not really being good enough. If they contact you, why not give it a shot, at worst you'll get an interesting interview experience out of it that you can one day share with your grandchildren

Comment: Whether you think you can or you think you can't, you're probably right. -- (paraphrase of) Henry Ford @remyabel

Comment: wait, are you using _gmail_ and _wondering_ how google knows your email address?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Pulling my comment into an answer...

That type of email you got is a pretty typical recruitment email. Not just for Google, but for a lot of other companies.

I got my job at Google through a similar process. Somebody liked one of my Stack Overflow answers and looked up my profile. After digging through a few links, he eventually found my email address and sent me a very similar recruitment email.

I decided to follow through on the email. And after a weeks, they flew me into California for an interview. In the end, I got the job.

---

As a Google employee, I can confirm that in your case, both the sender email and the person are legit.

So it's up to you to decide what you want to do.

Comment: I think Jon Skeet is the only Google employee who's on StackOverflow all day. I certainly am not. Check my activity tab and you'll notice it's pretty slow. I do however keep a few tabs open as well as an auto-refresher on the homepage of SO. But I only occasionally glance over at it.

Comment: Oh hey, I got a hat from this answer. Yay hats!!!!!

Comment: @Mysticial and now you have another Nice Answer meta badge :-)

Comment: +1 for authenticating this - personally I would have written it off as yet another good-looking-but-ultimately-a-scam type email.

Comment: @slugster It's usually good enough just to look at the sender email. There's no point in spoofing a sender email unless there's something that the email wants you to do (click on some link). Well written recruitment emails are personalized for the person that it is being sent to. So it's unlikely that a spammer will put that much effort into each target. (especially for people like us who are computer savvy and are less likely to fall for phishing scams)

Comment: You know we've really moved the baseline for participation when someone like Mysticial refers to his as "occasional" and "pretty slow".

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar email message today. While trying to decide if I should take it seriously, I learned about DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) and thought I'd add a note here for future readers.

DKIM uses digital signatures and public keys stored in DNS to allow recipients to verify that email did come from the claimed source. In the case of Gmail, it verifies the signature when it's present and presents related info when you click the down-arrow icon next to "to me". Here's the info Gmail showed me for my "Hello From Google!" message -- note the "signed-by" line.

[image: Gmail "to me" info]

Comment: OK, so? It's already been agreed those emails are indeed from Google

Comment: Some (not all) of those messages are from Google.

Comment: I can't really see why anyone will impersonate Google? You have any proof?

Comment: There are various scams related to job offers - search "job offer scam" for a long list of discussions on the topic. Many of the scams impersonate companies like Google because that's more likely to catch the attention of the target.