# Annoying E-Mails: Where did they get my mail-address?

Tags: discussion, spam, email

Today I received a spam message with the topic of n question at Stackoverflow:

> Topic: *Re: chrome.identity.getAuthToken cannot get Token in Chrome
>   Extension*
>
> Hi Ole,
>
> Just wondering if you ever got this question answered.  If not, maybe
>   a brief chat with a Javascript wizpert could help: link (Link removed)
>
> [...]

As this seems quite focussed on my SO-Post and my Mail is private: How did they do that? What can I do to stop that in the future?

Comment: Your G+ profile is liked from your profile.  Presumably your email is on there somewhere, or can be determined from information there

Comment: You're not the only one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218528/contact-from-wizpert-com-via-stackoverflow .

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/, under "Retrieve an authenticated user's email address."

Comment: What a bunch of disgusting spammers.

Comment: @Robert Harvey But I never authenticated the spammer with my Google- profile. (Or did you misunderstood my question?)

Comment: @Servy isn't there public either. *Of course* it IS possible to find my mail somewhere with enough energy (like doing a whois on my domain), but this mail just looks that much like an automated spam message that I do not expect that much "social engineering" there

Comment: A whois on your domain is trivNO CARRIER

Comment: Maybe related: [Someone contacted me by email but my email is not public](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207872/someone-contacted-me-by-email-but-my-email-is-not-public).