# Is there anything I can do if I get 3rd party about my SO question?

Tags: discussion, spam

I posted a question on StackOverflow:

[Java NumberFormat isn't respecting comma as decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821057/java-numberformat-isnt-respecting-comma-as-decimal-separator)

Then I got spam from a 3rd party trying to get me to go to their site to get an answer, instead of SO. I know SO can't stop the email spam from a 3rd party, but is there someway to find if they have any SO accounts and nuke this f'ing spammer?

> [image]

Comment: Well, you can shame them publicly here on Meta..

Comment: @MartijnPieters They'd probably just be happy that someone is posting their spam links publicly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wizpert seems to be getting quite the public shaming here recently

Comment: Those guys have been busy: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218528/contact-from-wizpert-com-via-stackoverflow and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221794/annoying-e-mails-where-did-they-get-my-mail-address .

Comment: I see your email is (3 clicks from) public, so there’s not a huge amount you can do. I think if you report it as spam to your provider they will eventually start getting their emails blocked across the board

Comment: The problem is that nuking any Stack Overflow accounts won't make any difference since the posts and your profile are public.

Comment: I got a similar (from the same person) e-mail a few days back. How the hell did he even get my e-mail id?!

Comment: @Ranveer: https://github.com/ranveeraggarwal, look near the left.

Comment: Oh damn! How stupid of me -_- But still, it has to be done *manually*. Do they have a team of people doing this?!

Comment: @Ranveer: not necessarily, a crawler would find this sort of information with relative ease.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yup! You're right. So I guess I should run a crawler on my account until I find a loose end.

Comment: CEO of company recomended  for programming help ... lol

Comment: @Servy I intentionally posted an image of the email instead of the text content to avoid offering any Page Rank or clickable connection to their sites.

Comment: wizpert.........heh,heh