# Letting other members contact me

Tags: discussion, email, contact

I have just read 5 other related messages which meta stackoverflow suggested as relevant and/or possible dupes. I didn't see this exactly addressed. This surprised me, as I would think it to be an obvious question that would interest zillions of users.

***Question:*** *Is it "okay" to put my E-mail address in my StackOverflow blurb thing* ?

I see that my E-mail address is already there; but private. Can I purposely make it public ?

I believe that my website is public  (somebody please correct me)

I have registered a bunch of domain names over the past couple of years, with an ancillary benefit: I can create/delete/recreate/etc. an address on the fly; even for one time use if needed

With this in mind, is there an official policy on publishing ones own E-mail address in ones Stack Overflow profile area ?

While I'm at it, is it okay to ask for advice on how to let others here contact me ?

Comment: You can put ([almost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139190/193563)) whatever you want in your profile area.

Comment: If you want to put your email address in your profile blurb, then that's fine.  That area is for whatever you want.  But, I don't think you should announce that in your questions/answers.  If someone wants to contact you, they can click on your profile.  I don't have my email, but I do have a link to my website and people have found how to contact me.  So, I think it's fine to have your email, just don't promote it.

Comment: If Stack Overflow's arguably most famous user, Jon Skeet, can have his email published in his user profile, I would assume you could too.

Comment: not-quite-dupe: [Rules for Profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31504/rules-for-profiles)

Comment: @AakashM ; Thanks.  Right on target.  +1

Comment: [The poster child for what you can put in your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, duh; Okay, then my profile blurb will probably be okay.  Thanks for the, uhm, educational reflection !  (+1 for you, sir)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your E-Mail address in your "about me" field.

Nobody has any problem with that. There is no offical policy regulating this.

As a consequence of making your E-Mail address publicly visible, you may occasionally get

- Requests for help
- "Invitations" to other web sites that do something similar to SO
- "Invitations" to get your questions answered at [some spammy tech help web site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218528/contact-from-wizpert-com-via-stackoverflow?rq=1)

Comment: On the other hand, if you put an image of a unicorn handbag in your profile.........

Comment: I do get a lot of E-Mail complimenting me on it, that's true.

Comment: _"occasionally"_?

Comment: Assuming text can be considered offensive enough to be removed, you could probably create an e-mail address to just contain that, and then putting that (your e-mail address) in your "about me" probably wouldn't be appropriate.