# Should we remove personal information (name/email) from answers?

Tags: discussion

I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530122/329801) where the answerer included their name/email in an answer, and solicits further communication there.

Should these details be removed? They add nothing to the answer, and in theory any discussion about the solution should be recorded on Stack Overflow (for future users' reference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the author's name from the posts - signatures [do not belong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts?rq=1) in answers (or questions, for that matter) as the system automatically puts the user's name below a post.

It seems to be [allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228099/letting-other-members-contact-me) to let other members contact you via e-mail, if you desire so, but your personal profile page is a better place to leave your e-mail address.