# Area51-related spam email received

Tags: discussion, area-51, spam, email

Just received this email (which I consider as spam):

> **FW: Arabic Language Proposal on the StackExchange network**
>
> Date: Sat, 4 Oct 2014 23:31:33 -0400
>   Subject: Arabic Language Proposal on the StackExchange network
>   From: w**********d@gmail.com
>   To: a*********1@hotmail.com
>
> وأخيرا، دخلت الاقتراح مرحلتها الثانية، وها هي الرابطة:
>
> http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022/arabic-language?referrer=L2p8uioxGYf30j48QTDmGA2
>
> اتبع الرابط إلى صفحة الاقتراح، ثم اضغط على زر "Commit" اﻷخضر، شكرا

While it may be a coincidence that I as a Stack Exchange user receive this spam, I still wonder whether someone managed to misuse Stack Exchange for spamming.

**So my question is:**

Is the above spam email an indicator that someone might use a possible security vulnerability in Stack Exchange to spam other users?

*(Or it this actually a feature I've never discovered until now?)*

**Update 1**

I've just followed the link with the "referrer=L2p8uioxGYf30j48QTDmGA2" which leads to [this user](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/57603/). He/she claims:

> I currently act as a temporary moderator for Islam Stackexchange.

I've once registered for this site "islam.stackexchange.com". As [this posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207873/133056) states, a moderator can access my email address.

I might be wrong, but my wild guess here is that a moderator is spamming users. Could this be the case?

**Update 2**

To the closing-voters: If my guess is true and some moderator is involved, then it seems to me this is not releated to the possible duplicate article.

Comment: Can still your email in the first quote.  By the way, were you signed up for the Definition phase?

Comment: @Omen I think I should leave the addresses of the spammer visible since it might help track down the source of the "issue". I have _not_ committed to the proposal.

Comment: Fair enough - it does seem very bizarre, as if it were an official email from SE, it should be from the Area 51 team

Comment: This did not come from Stack Exchange, and not from any official "share this" feature they have.

Comment: @UweKeim no, you did not obscure anything, if you have then you forgot to edit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've obscured _my_ email address to "***.****@gmail.com". I've you think it is worth obscuring _all_ addresses, feel free to go ahead.

Comment: @UweKeim refresh your browser, you have some weird cache. I see your email, starting with "w" and ending with "d".

Comment: @ShadowWizard That is not mine ;-)

Comment: the email could have been sent as a BCC

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207872/someone-contacted-me-by-email-but-my-email-is-not-public

Comment: This is really something you should report *privately* to the Stack Exchange team. You're no better than them if you're going around publishing email addresses.

Comment: @animuson How (technically) should I do it? Is there a support email address or some other process?

Comment: Use the standard contact us form (linked in the footer) or just shoot an email to team@stackexchange.com

Comment: *Or it this actually a feature I've never discovered until now?* - As you said that user is a moderator on Islam, he might have read your email id (yes, moderators can view email id but they shouldn't see unless required). So he might have picked up few email ids requesting to support Arabic SO as he can get most of the  arab speaking users from Islam.SE but in a way this is kinda wrong, but can't say spamming. He wants to support a site so he mailed random people but yes, can't view ids for mailing users personally.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Using PII for purposes other than moderation of the site is a violation of the moderator agreement and the SE privacy policy. It's not just "kinda wrong", it is explicitly forbidden for moderators to do this. (I don't know if PII was used or the address was public in this specific case)

Comment: Note, I've edited the header out of the post, as it contains emails. We're aware of it, and have acted.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks. I've also edited the remaining emails out.

Comment: I was going to ask this question myself: I got one too.

Comment: At the downvoter: Anything I did wrong in my question?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We've received reports of this, and we've contacted the folks involved. It's nothing nefarious, just some very enthused users that want to see a site go forward, but going about promoting it in the wrong ways.

I've contacted them privately, we'll take it from here.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like it is either sent in error, or indeed spam, especially as you were not involved in the Definition phase.

Any notifications about a site proceeding to commitment phase should come from the Area 51 team.