# What can/should be done (if anything) about spam addresses to my Stack Exchange address?

Tags: support

I have received two unsolicited advertisements to an address that has never been given to anyone except Stack Exchange (SE), and they are not from SE.  The address hasn't even been used to log into SE because all the conflicting instructions I've found for making the change refer to links or buttons that no longer exist.

I'm asking about what can be done in terms of SE, not a general response to spam. (I know about detection and filtering methods and ways to report, etc.) I won't be surprised if the answer is "nothing", but it "doesn't hurt to ask."

Comment: How easily guessable is your address? Spammers do just run through every common permutation

Comment: SE at a domain that has very little traffic and *zero* content pertinent to SE nor to the spamvertised service.  Oddity is that it is a service aimed at I.T. people.  I'd think that they would understand that spamming such people is a good way to make enemies, not get business.

Comment: I dunno about that... wgroleau@google.com!

Comment: @Won't: Dunno about what?  Are you saying that you guessed my address? If so, (1) that address is *not* mine; and (2) if it were, what would that prove about anything else above?

Comment: Then why did you email me back at that address and say, "Yeah, you got me, bro.  I owe you a hundred bucks like you said in that email.  What's your paypal?"  Huh?  Tell me THAT!

Comment: I have no idea whether you are lying or whether the address is real and whoever owns it actually responded.  Again, it is not my address.  Nor does it have any resemblance to the address the spammer used.

Answer (score 5):

You have a five year old account, and appear to be using the default Gravatar image for your avatar. Those have had some issues (See [Is Gravatar a privacy risk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/is-gravatar-a-privacy-risk), [Is using Gravatar a security risk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/is-using-gravatar-a-security-risk), and others in the top-voted section of the [gravatar](/questions/tagged/gravatar) tag). Since about three years ago, Stack Exchange [takes some effort to prevent your e-mail leaking this way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204540/226203), but they didn't swap out existing avatars for anyone that had already signed up. This could easily be the way your e-mail address leaked.

Comment: So the default image is actually taken from Gravatar?  I did not know; thought it was just some graphic.  I will promptly change it!  Although, your second link says something about having a Gravatar account, which I don't.

Comment: @WGroleau Yeah, you should be able to right-click the image on your profile page, hit Properties or whatever similar option your browser has, and see the image's URL. Has the md5 of your email address right there. It's how I verified you were still on Gravatar before posting this answer.

Comment: So, when I attempted to change my e-mail address in late 2014 or early 2015, SE sent the new address to Gravatar and got that MD5 in reply?  And the MD5 is reversible to determine address?

Answer (score 1):

Not much to do. I guess you have been hit by some 'check all possible email addresses and their permutations' spam bot. I really doubt if this is related to SE at all. SE does not give email addresses of their users to third parties. Never!

So judging the above, either SE has to be hacked, which is unlikely since you seem to be the only one receiving such mail, or they have guessed your email address correctly 'by accident'.