# I changed my Stack Overflow account email address. Suddenly, my username and photo changed too

Tags: support, login, merge-accounts, email-addresses

I was recently laid off from my company. I changed my Stack Overflow account's email address from my work email to my personal email. Upon doing this, my username, which was "Umbrella_Programmer," suddenly changed to "Brainless" and my profile image changed from the Umbrella Laboratories logo to my personal email image.

Was my password stolen, or is this some kind of weird bug? I googled "Stackoverflow Brainless" and found two users: *Brainless* and *brainless*, but neither of those people are me.

I have changed my username and image back to their originals, and I changed the password to a new password.

Comment: perhaps your work email had username brainless

Comment: gonna log on to a sock

Comment: cant repro maybe someone did hack i dunno

Comment: @zixuan no the work email did not have that name

Comment: I am brainless !

Answer (score 23):

You had two accounts registered, one with both of the different email addresses you used. When you confirmed the second email address to one of your accounts, it triggered an automatic merge since you had now verified the email to both accounts. We do not allow multiple accounts to exist with the same verified email address.

The other account was created in 2017, two years before your current account. It never had any participation, so you probably forgot you ever created it. We always perform merges into the lower account Id, so that one was chosen and the display name and profile details of it were kept.

Comment: Thanks! But why the name "Brainless"?

Comment: That is the display name you had set for the old account.

Comment: Brainless!!!!!!

Comment: @animuson I guarantee I did not set the old account to that name ;)

Comment: @Umbrella_Programmer I can vouch for never having done many things that I did

Answer (score 1):

The last time I looked (which was multiple years ago, I did a quick meta search but didn't find anything recent that was relevant), Stack Exchange has the option to pull your photo from a third party service named [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/). If you have ever used your personal e-mail with Gravatar, even on a website that has nothing to do with Stack Exchange, your profile update could have caused the system to reach out to Gravatar servers and retrieve whatever you last set with them.

Gravatar provides [a tool to check on what it knows about a given address](https://en.gravatar.com/site/check/).

For more, see the very old meta posts [Is Gravatar a privacy risk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/is-gravatar-a-privacy-risk) and [Is using Gravatar a security risk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/is-using-gravatar-a-security-risk).